# Optimize PostgreSQL for a lot of INSERTS and bytea updates

Tags: postgresql-9.3, insert, performance, database-tuning, bytea, performance-tuning

What we have (software):

- **PostrgeSQL 9.3** with base configuration (no changes in `postgresql.conf`)
- **Windows 7 64 bit**

Hardware:

- Intel Core i7-3770 3.9 Ghz
- 32 Gb RAM
- WDC WD10EZRX-00L4HBAta Drive (1000Gb, SATA III)

So, we have to load into DB aprox. **100.000.000** rows with **bytea** column, and more simple **500.000.000** rows (without LOBs). There are 2 `varchar` indexes on 1st table (with 13, 19 length) and 2 `varchar` indexes on 2nd table (18, 10 lengths).
There are also sequences for id generation for each table.

By now these operations are doing with 8 connections in parallel with 50 JDBC batch size. The picture below demonstrates system load: it is zero-load on `postgresql` processes. After 24 hours of loading we have loaded only 10.000.000 rows which is very slow result.

[image]

We are asking for help in tuning `PostrgreSQL` configuration in purposes of:

1) for ultra fast loading this amount of data, it is once-only operation, so it could be temporary configuration

2) for production mode for doing moderate number of SELECTs into these 2 tables by their indexes without join and without sorting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For `insert` performance, see [speeding up insert performance in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206600/how-to-speed-up-insertion-performance-in-postgresql) and [bulk insert in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/758945/398670).

<s>You're wasting your time with JDBC batching for `insert`. [PgJDBC doesn't do anything useful with `insert` batches, it just runs each statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12648498/398670).</s> <-- This is no longer true in newer PgJDBC versions, which can now batch prepared statements to reduce round-trip times considerably. But it's still better to:

Use `COPY` instead; see [PgJDBC batch copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12648498/398670) and the [`CopyManager`](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html). As for number of concurrent loaders: Aim for a couple per disk, if the operations are disk I/O bound. Eight is probably the most you'll want.

For your "production mode" I suggest loading a sample of data, setting up the queries you expect to run, and using `explain analyze` to investigate performance. For testing purposes only, use the `enable_` params to explore different plan selections. Set the query planner cost parameters (`random_page_cost`, `seq_page_cost`, `effective_cache_size`, etc) appropriately for your system, and make sure `shared_buffers` is set appropriately.  Continue to monitor as you add a simulated production workload, using the `auto_explain` module, `log_min_duration_statement` setting, the `pg_stat_statements` extension, etc.

For details, see the PostgreSQL user manual. I suggest popping back here when you have a more concrete problem with `explain analyze` query execution details, etc.

Comment: This is an amazaing answer! Thx.